# Extract specific struct field of a decoded column in Spark Dataframe

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a decoded column in a spark dataframe that contains JSON data. For example,

row 1: {'id': 1, 'name': 'Slatan', 'surname': 'Yav', 'age': 24} 
row 2: {'id': 2, 'name': 'Nikos', 'surname': 'Stef', 'age': 34} 
row 3: {'id': 3, 'name': 'Panos', 'surname': 'Rodes', 'age': 44}

And I want to extract only the "name", "surname", "age" and add them to a Spark data frame.

**My approach**

```
schema = StructType(
    [
      StructField('name', StringType(), True),
      StructField('surname', StringType(), True),
      StructField('age', IntegerType(), True)
    ]
)

final_df=None
final_df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)
columns_selected=schema.fieldNames()

final_df=final_df.union(avro_decoded.withColumn("Body_decoded", from_json("Body_decoded", schema)).select(col( 'Body_decoded.*columns_selected')))
```

But I get errors. How can I fill the final_df (spark dataframe) with only the fields of name, surname and exclude id value?

**Error**

```
'No such struct field *columns_selected in name, surname;'
```

Body column before decoding

[image]

```
avro_decoded=read_avro_data.withColumn('Body_decoded', decode(read_avro_data.Body, charset="UTF-8")).select("Body_decoded")

avro_decoded.printSchema()
```

returns:

```
root
 |-- Body_decoded: string (nullable = true)
```

Than you in advance for any advice.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: 'No such struct field *columns_selected in name, surname;'

Comment: Try to print your dataFrame and see what is inside. Sometimes it capitalizes the first letter when reading in dataFrame

Comment: When I print the column Body_decoded I get a spark series with rows like the values written in the start of my question. (json rows)...Body_decoded is a column of the avro_decoded spark df

Comment: can you post lt here with code? I can't tell how you are trying to access it.

Comment: can u post `.printSchema()` of ur dataframe

Comment: Please check my edit changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right approach in trying to use **`from_json`**, however, your *json was not formatted correctly for spark,* as you have a **`MapType with different data type for values(string and integer)`**, therefore, just wrap your integer with quotes using **`regexp_replace`**, then use **`from_json`** to **`select`** your desired columns as shown below.

```
df.show() #sample dataframe

#+---------------------------------------------------------+
#|Body_decoded                                             |
#+---------------------------------------------------------+
#|{'id': 1, 'name': 'Slatan', 'surname': 'Yav', 'age': 24} |
#|{'id': 2, 'name': 'Nikos', 'surname': 'Stef', 'age': 34} |
#|{'id': 3, 'name': 'Panos', 'surname': 'Rodes', 'age': 44}|
#+---------------------------------------------------------+
#root
 #|-- Body_decoded: string (nullable = true) #schema


from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

schema=MapType(StringType(),StringType())
columns_selected=['name','surname']

df.withColumn("Body_decoded", F.from_json(F.regexp_replace("Body_decoded",'[^"\d,]?(\d+)',"'$1'")\
                                              ,schema))\
  .select(*["Body_decoded.{}".format(x) for x in columns_selected]).show()

#+------+-------+
#|name  |surname|
#+------+-------+
#|Slatan|Yav    |
#|Nikos |Stef   |
#|Panos |Rodes  |
#+------+-------+
```

Comment: Ok I can see your point, but what if I have different type of data types (StringType(), IntegerType()) ? Why you use MapType instead of StructField?

Comment: Also MapType() gives me error: ```TypeError: __init__() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 15 were given``` ....I give 15 because I have 14 columns to iterate and not only 3 as the example I presented. My data are sensitive that is why I presented dummy data. In my example I have multiple data types. Not only StringType data

Comment: `MapType(StringType(),StringType())` means that key is string and value is string for all columns, no need to give 15 position args, the 2 will suffice, as long as each key and value is wrapped in single/double quotes the from_json will work. U can use structfield to but whats the point of writing all that line by line when u can just tell the maptype that all keys and values are strings. and once u have ur columns aligned, u can apply .cast to cast to whatever format u like

Comment: Yeah you have a point. Although this ```*["Body_decoded.{}".format(x) for x in columns_selected]``` saved me

Comment: Glad to help, feel free to upvote/accept answer to close the thread

Comment: Mohammad can you please also explain to me how ```regexp_replace("Body_decoded",'[^"\d,]?(\d+)',"'$1'")``` works with an example? Ty

Comment: regex is not my strongest suit but the code bascially finds wherever there is a number throughout the string, and wraps it in single quotes, so `1232 213 my` will be converted to `'1232' '213' my`